# jQuery image zoom that allows scroll on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

I have been through panzoom.js, EasyZoom.js, elevate-zoom, and jack moore's jQuery zoom trying to find a plugin that does an inner zoom. All of these zoom plugins function on desktop and mobile, except on mobile when my image covers the whole window in landscape orientation.  No plugin I have found has a taphold-move zoom for mobile, so that you can still scroll the page if your image fills the window.

I've tried editing the touch functions in these plugins to no avail.  What is the best practice in this situation?

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    if ($(window).width() > 992) {
        $.each($('img.panzoom'), function(index) {
                $(this)
                .wrap('<span style="display:inline-block"></span>')
                .css('display', 'block')
                .parent()
                .zoom({
                    on: 'mouseover',
                    url: $(this).attr('data-zoom-image'),
                    target: $(this).parent()
                });
        });
    } else {
      // mobile functional zoom plugin code
    }
```